# How can set value for mteHotContextName when using monitor process in SNMP

Tags: linux, rhel, trap, snmp

I'm using RHEL 5, I tried to find some way to set value for set value of mteHotContextName or mteHotTargetName of DISMAN-EVENT-MIB but I can't find the answer.

I searched in stacoverflow but nothing i can do:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13156289/net-snmp-getting-more-detail-into-disman-traps

My conf in snmpd file:

```
# Processes Monitoring
rwuser userrw
rouser userro
createUser userrw MD5 "userrw" DES
createUser userro MD5 "userro" DES
agentSecName userro
monitor -r 5 -o prNames   -o prErrMessage  "process table" != prErrorFlag

proc my-service 1 1
```

snmptrapd result:

```
2016-10-31 07:56:51 localhost.localdomain [UDP: [127.0.0.1]:58300]:
DISMAN-EVENT-MIB::sysUpTimeInstance = Timeticks: (17512) 0:02:55.12     SNMPv2-MIB::snmpTrapOID.0 = OID: DISMAN-EVENT-MIB::mteTriggerFired      DISMAN-EVENT-MIB::mteHotTrigger.0 = STRING: process table    DISMAN-EVENT-MIB::mteHotTargetName.0 = STRING:   DISMAN-EVENT-MIB::mteHotContextName.0 = STRING:         DISMAN-EVENT-MIB::mteHotOID.0 = OID: UCD-SNMP-MIB::prErrorFlag.1        DISMAN-EVENT-MIB::mteHotValue.0 = INTEGER: 1  UCD-SNMP-MIB::prNames.1 = STRING: my-service      UCD-SNMP-MIB::prErrMessage.1 = STRING: No my-service process running.
```

mteHotContextName is always empty.

Is there anyway to config or add value for mteHotContextName ? Or how can I modify any source code of snmp to do this?